# Custom formatting of validation summary and errors

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, .net-core

## The problem

#### Summary

For the validation summary you usually have something like this:

```
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="..."></div>
```

which, in case there are errors with an empty string as field/attribute will be displayed inside that div within a `<ul>` list.

What if I want to display them using a sequence of `div`s with a specific `class` attribute? Or any other custom formatting?

#### Field validation

For field validation you usually do:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label asp-for="OldPassword"></label>
    <input asp-for="OldPassword" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="OldPassword" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
```

and the error gets inserted as text within the `span` element.

I'm using a template that requires the `has-errors` class to be applied to the `form-group` `div` element in case there are errors because it needs to style both the label and the input.

It also requires the `span` to be a `div` (for some unknown reasons) and surprisingly enough changing the `span` to `div` prevents the div from inserting the text of the error; not to mention that wrapping the `span` inside a `div` yields that problem that the `div` has proper spacing applied to it so even if there are no errors the div shows an annoying space.

## Question (tl; dr)

What is the most idiomatic way of handling custom form validation formatting (trying to DRY, since my application has many forms) with custom rules like the ones shown above?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here are some extension points that you can consider to provide custom rendering for validation summary and field validation errors:

- Customize existing validation tag helpers (Register new `IHtmlGenerator`)
- Create new validation tag helpers (Register new `Tag Helpers`)

### Customize existing validation tag helpers

[`asp-validation-summary`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/v5.0.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ValidationSummaryTagHelper.cs) and [`asp-validation-for`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/tree/v5.0.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.TagHelpers/src/ValidationMessageTagHelper.cs) tag helpers use  `GenerateValidationSummary` and `GenerateValidationMessage` methods of the registered implementation of `IHtmlGenerator` service which is [`DefaultHtmlGenerator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs) by default.

You can provide your custom implementation deriving `DefaultHtmlGenerator` and overriding those methods, then register the service at startup. This way those tag helpers will use your custom implementation.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
    services.AddTransient<IHtmlGenerator, MyHtmlGenerator>();
}
```

Here is the link to [source code of `DefaultHtmlGenerator`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v5.0.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/DefaultHtmlGenerator.cs) to help you to customize the implementation.

***Example - Creating a new implementation IHtmlGenerator***

Here is just a simple example to show required namespaces and methods and simply what can goes into your custom implementation. After you provided custom implementation, don't forget to register it in `ConfigureServices` like what I did above.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Antiforgery;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.Internal;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Text.Encodings.Web;

namespace ValidationSampleWebApplication
{
    public class MyHtmlGenerator : DefaultHtmlGenerator
    {
        public MyHtmlGenerator(IAntiforgery antiforgery, IOptions<MvcViewOptions> optionsAccessor, IModelMetadataProvider metadataProvider, IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory, HtmlEncoder htmlEncoder, ValidationHtmlAttributeProvider validationAttributeProvider) 
            : base(antiforgery, optionsAccessor, metadataProvider, urlHelperFactory, htmlEncoder, validationAttributeProvider)
        {
        }
        public override TagBuilder GenerateValidationMessage(ViewContext viewContext, ModelExplorer modelExplorer, string expression, string message, string tag, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return base.GenerateValidationMessage(viewContext, modelExplorer, expression, message, tag, htmlAttributes);
        }
        public override TagBuilder GenerateValidationSummary(ViewContext viewContext, bool excludePropertyErrors, string message, string headerTag, object htmlAttributes)
        {
            return base.GenerateValidationSummary(viewContext, excludePropertyErrors, message, headerTag, htmlAttributes);
        }
    }
}
```

### Create new validation tag helpers

You also can [author your custom tag helpers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/tag-helpers/authoring?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=aspnetcore-5.0). To do so, it's enough to derive from `TagHelper` and override `Process` methods.

Then you can simply register created tag helpers in the view or globally in `_ViewImports.cshtml`:

```
@using ValidationSampleWebApplication
@using ValidationSampleWebApplication.Models
@addTagHelper *, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers
@addTagHelper *, ValidationSampleWebApplication
```

Also when creating the custom tag helpers for validation you can consider:

- Creating the validation tag helper from scratch
- Drive from existing tag-helper classes

***Example - Adding hasError class to a form-group div***

In this example, I've created a `asp-myvalidation-for` which can be applied on `div` elements this way `<div class="form-group" asp-myvalidation-for="LastName">` and will add `hasError` class to `div` if the specified field has validation error. Don't forget to register it in `_ViewImports.cshtml` like what I did above.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding;

namespace ValidationSampleWebApplication
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = MyValidationForAttributeName)]
    public class MyValidationTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        private const string MyValidationForAttributeName = "asp-myvalidation-for";

        [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
        [ViewContext]
        public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName(MyValidationForAttributeName)]
        public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            base.Process(context, output);
            ModelStateEntry entry;
            ViewContext.ViewData.ModelState.TryGetValue(For.Name, out entry);
            if (entry != null && entry.Errors.Count > 0)
            {
                var builder = new TagBuilder("div");
                builder.AddCssClass("hasError");
                output.MergeAttributes(builder);   
            }
        }
    }
}
```

***Example - Adding `field-validation-error` class to a form-group div***

In the following example, I've added `div` support to the standard `asp-validation-for` tag helper. The existing tag helper just supports div element. Here I've added `div` support to the `asp-validation-for` tag helper and in case of error, it will add `field-validation-error` otherwise, in valid cases the `div` will have `field-validation-valid` class.

The default behavior of the tag is in a way that it doesn't make any change in content of the tag if the tag has contents. So for adding the tag helper to an empty `span` will add validation error to span, but for a div having some contents, it just changes the class of div.  Don't forget to register it in `_ViewImports.cshtml` like what I did above.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.TagHelpers;

namespace ValidationSampleWebApplication
{
    [HtmlTargetElement("div", Attributes = ValidationForAttributeName)]
    public class MytValidationMessageTagHelper : ValidationMessageTagHelper
    {
        private const string ValidationForAttributeName = "asp-validation-for";
        public MytValidationMessageTagHelper(IHtmlGenerator generator) : base(generator)
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So just to make sure I understand: the solution to the second problem (field validation) would be to add `asp-validation-for` to the `form-group` `div` and build the proper tag there copying `label` and `input` and adding classes to those too?

Comment: The answer generally shows you how you can customize out put of *existing* tag-helpers or register new tag helpers. I added some more details to the answer to make it more useful. About your specific requirement for applying some class to the div element, you need to create tag helper. I added two examples to the answer which you can use both of them.

Answer (score 0):

Using a custom tag helper i came up with a following solution:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("ul", Attributes = AttributeName)]
public class ValidationSummaryLiItemsTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string AttributeName = "model-validation-summary-list";

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var errors = ViewContext.ModelState.Where(x => x.Key == "").SelectMany(x => x.Value.Errors).ToList();
        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            output.Content.AppendFormat("<li>{0}</li>", error.ErrorMessage);
        }

        if (errors.Any() == false)
            output.SuppressOutput();
    }
}
```

Later i can use it like that:

```
<ul class="some-css-class" id="some-id-name" model-validation-summary-list></ul>
```

Then, for example, i can customize the `ul` container directly with bootstrap classes or add any html attribute.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be quite old and we are currently at .NET 7.0, but for me the solution by kzaw was not working as it is actually getting the error messages where the element name is empty -> Where(x => x.Key == ""). I have added a few lines in order to show in the element name in the summary. After that I'm creating an anonymous object that is holding the key (the element) and the error messages for this element - in case there are multiple validations failed for specific element/input field:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("ul", Attributes = AttributeName)]
public class CustomValidationSummaryTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    private const string AttributeName = "validation-summary-list";

    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    [ViewContext]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }


    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        var errors = ViewContext
            .ModelState
            .Where(x => x.Key != "")
            .Select(x => new
            {
                Key = x.Key,
                Errors = x.Value.Errors.ToList()
            })
            .ToList();

        foreach (var error in errors)
        {
            var keyErrors = error.Errors;

            foreach (var keyError in keyErrors)
            {
                output.Content.AppendHtml($"<li>{error.Key} - {keyError.ErrorMessage}</li>");
            }


        }

        if (errors.Any() == false)
            output.SuppressOutput();
    }
}
```